# Consuming class libraries built using .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, .net-core

I have a written a .NET Core class library. It is currently targeting `netcoreapp1.1`. I have a windows service that references this library. The windows service targets .NET 4.6.2.

When I try to start the win service while referencing MyLib.dll that is found in the `bin/Debug` folder of the MyLib project I get the following error in Windows Event Viewer:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

`System.Runtime` is a dependency of `MyLib.dll`. If I publish my library in VS 2017 it creates a NuGet package. When I add that package to my win service project, it appears to install all the dependent packages. When I try to start the service in this configuration I get the following in Event Viewer:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MyLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

I am not sure how I go about getting interoperability between the windows service and the library.

Answer (score 0):

Digging into it a bit more, I was able to at least solve the issues.

I still don't entirely understand the why of it, but I got it all working.

The first exception seems to be caused by a conflict in targeted frameworks. If the class library targets .NET Standard 1.4, and the service targets .NET Framework 4.6.1 everything seems to compile and run successfully.

The second exception seemed to be caused by a mismatch in the build platform targeted by both the library and service projects. By switching the platform targeted by the service project to x64 from the default AnyCPU, the format exception is resolved.

Comment: Yup that's true. You can find more info on which frameworks supports which .NET Standard here: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md